# How can I trigger multiple hover actions on links when hovering over a div?

Tags: html, css, hover

Im trying to trigger multiple hover effects when hovering over my main div. I can´t figure out how make the line animate on all three links at the same time, and whether this can be done in only css or if i have to use javascript, and im not finding the right solution to previous posts. Here is the code:

```css
.right-project-headline h2 a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    position: relative;
}
.right-project-headline h2 a::before, .right-project-headline h2 a::after {
  content: '';
  background: black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 55%;
  height: 3px;
  width: 0;
}
.right-project-headline h2 a::before {
  left: 0;
}
.right-project-headline h2 a::after {
  right: 0;
  transition: width 500ms ease;
}
.right-project-headline h2 a:hover::before {
  width: 100%;
  transition: width 500ms ease;
}
.right-project-headline h2 a:hover::after {
  width: 100%;
  background: transparent;
  transition: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="right-project-headline">
  <h2><a href="industrial-rev.html">The</a></h2>
  <h2><a href="industrial-rev.html">Industrial</a></h2>
  <h2><a href="industrial-rev.html">Revolutions</a></h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

I would simplify your code like below and apply hover effect on the parent container

```css
.right-project-headline h2 a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  background: linear-gradient(black, black) no-repeat;
  background-size: 0% 4px; /*left:0 top:55%*/
  background-position: 0% 55%; /*left:0 top:55%*/
  transition: background-size 0.5s, background-position 0s 0.5s;
}

.right-project-headline:hover h2 a {
  background-size: 100% 4px; /*width:100% height:4px*/
  background-position: 100% 55%; /*right:0 top:55%*/
}
```

```html
<div class="right-project-headline">
  <h2><a href="industrial-rev.html">The</a></h2>
  <h2><a href="industrial-rev.html">Industrial</a></h2>
  <h2><a href="industrial-rev.html">Revolutions</a></h2>
</div>
```

Here is another syntax for background-position (more intuitive):

```css
.right-project-headline h2 a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  background: linear-gradient(black, black) no-repeat;
  background-size: 0% 4px; 
  background-position: left 0 top 55%; 
  transition: background-size 0.5s, background-position 0s 0.5s;
}

.right-project-headline:hover h2 a {
  background-size: 100% 4px; 
  background-position: right 0 top 55%; 
}
```

```html
<div class="right-project-headline">
  <h2><a href="industrial-rev.html">The</a></h2>
  <h2><a href="industrial-rev.html">Industrial</a></h2>
  <h2><a href="industrial-rev.html">Revolutions</a></h2>
</div>
```

Another one with the shorthand version and less of code:

```css
.right-project-headline h2 a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  background: linear-gradient(black, black) var(--p,0%) 55%/var(--p,0%) 4px no-repeat;
  transition: background-size 0.5s, background-position 0s 0.5s;
}

.right-project-headline:hover h2 a {
  --p:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="right-project-headline">
  <h2><a href="industrial-rev.html">The</a></h2>
  <h2><a href="industrial-rev.html">Industrial</a></h2>
  <h2><a href="industrial-rev.html">Revolutions</a></h2>
</div>
```

Comment: Good one, your effort worths a +1!

Comment: Love the use of less code, but this version is a little bit buggy if you are not hovering on the link enough to finish the animation, then it will bounce back to the left instead of going right. But thanks anyways :)

Comment: @KongGeorg increase the speed a little to be sure it will finish ;)

Answer (score 1):

You have to add `:hover` to your `div` in CSS and not to your `a` elements.

This is selector for a in div

```
div a
```

This is selector for hovered a in div

```
div a:hover
```

And this is selector for a in hovered div

```
 div:hover a
```

So this should do the trick

```
.right-project-headline h2 a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    position: relative;
}
.right-project-headline h2 a::before, .right-project-headline h2 a::after {
  content: '';
  background: black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 55%;
  height: 3px;
  width: 0;
}
.right-project-headline h2 a::before {
  left: 0;
}
.right-project-headline h2 a::after {
  right: 0;
  transition: width 500ms ease;
}
.right-project-headline:hover h2 a::before {
  width: 100%;
  transition: width 500ms ease;
}
.right-project-headline:hover h2 a::after {
  width: 100%;
  background: transparent;
  transition: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to catch the hover event on the element with class `.right-project-headline` and then apply the style to the `<a>` elements inside it, like this:

```
.right-project-headline:hover a::before {
  width: 100%;
  transition: width 500ms ease;
}

.right-project-headline:hover a::after {
  width: 100%;
  background: transparent;
  transition: 0;
}
```

**Complete Example:**

```css
.right-project-headline {
   border: 1px solid red;
}

.right-project-headline a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    position: relative;
}

.right-project-headline a::before, .right-project-headline a::after {
  content: '';
  background: black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 55%;
  height: 3px;
  width: 0;
}

.right-project-headline a::before {
  left: 0;
}

.right-project-headline a::after {
  right: 0;
  transition: width 500ms ease;
}

.right-project-headline:hover a::before {
  width: 100%;
  transition: width 500ms ease;
}

.right-project-headline:hover a::after {
  width: 100%;
  background: transparent;
  transition: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="right-project-headline">
  <h2><a href="industrial-rev.html">The</a></h2>
  <h2><a href="industrial-rev.html">Industrial</a></h2>
  <h2><a href="industrial-rev.html">Revolutions</a></h2>
</div>
```